# video is unplayable after adding static urls

Tags: django

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import homepageview
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',homepageview),



]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

im getting into /static/video/videoname.mp4
and its showing as shown in the fig.

[image: this is what it is displaying on entering into the url]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: no error, its working in mozilla, not in safari.